# How to force Thymeleaf to show attribute with empty value?

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-el, spring-expression-language

I'm using Thymeleaf 3.0.11 with Spring 4.3.22, no Boot. Have this code:

`<tbody class="clientdata section" th:data-id="${formModel?.client?.person?.userId ?: ''}">`

It works fine when the userId has a value. Then the output is, for example:

`<tbody class="clientdata section" data-id="178051">`

However, when the userId is null, the attribute disappears altogether:

`<tbody class="clientdata section">`

If i specify some dummy value in case of null userId, it works fine:

`<tbody class="clientdata section" th:data-id="${formModel?.client?.person?.userId ?: '0'}">`

But why not just render attribute with empty value? I.e. i would like it to render:

`<tbody class="clientdata section" data-id="">`

in case the userId is null.

Comment: Not possible in Thymeleaf, as far as I know.

Comment: I did not find any way either. Finally i took the dummy value approach, and adjusted the JavaScript that uses the ```data-id``` attribute.